# Pagination in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I am trying to achieve pagination in Oracle 11g with following query:

> SELECT *   FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY
> general_compliance_Details.ID) R,
> general_compliance.*,
> get_entity.*,
> general_compliance_Details.*,
> GSTN_STATE_JURIS_DETAILS.*,
> etm_gl_district.*
> FROM general_compliance_details
> LEFT JOIN get_Entity
> ON get_entity.gstin = general_compliance_details.gstin
> LEFT JOIN general_compliance
> ON general_compliance.id =
> general_compliance_details.general_compliance_id
> LEFT JOIN get_entity_status
> ON get_entity_status.gstin =
> general_compliance_details.gstin
> LEFT JOIN GSTN_STATE_JURIS_DETAILS
> ON get_Entity.PPBZDTLS_STJD = GSTN_STATE_JURIS_DETAILS.code
> LEFT JOIN etm_gl_district
> ON GSTN_STATE_JURIS_DETAILS.dist_cd =
> etm_gl_district.district_code
> WHERE     general_compliance_details.general_compliance_id = '2'
> AND general_compliance_details.status = '0'
> AND general_compliance.form_type = '1')  WHERE R >= 100 AND R <= 200

But it is giving error `Exception111ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` but my all columns are defined using table.column_name.

Please help.

Comment: The many `.*` are likely the problem.  If two tables happen to have a column by the same name, this could cause an error.

Comment: "but my all columns are defined using table.column_name" no they are not. Using i.e. `... general_compliance.*,get_entity.*...` star doesn't qualify the column name with the table name, if for instance these two mentioned tables have ID as column then it will throw that error.

Comment: Thanks for comment, its resolved now.